# How to save Dictionary object to bin file in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary, save, bin

This is VBA case. I want to save Dictionary object to bin file and put it again back to Dictionary later. This object should be the only content of bin file. In general I am stuck on:

> Compile error: Can not Get or Put an object reference variable or a
> variable of user-defined type containing an object reference

Relevant part of code looks like this:

```
Public generalListOfAddIns As Object

Public Type BinaryCapsuleType
    forObject As Object
End Type

Public Sub CreateGeneralListOfAddIns()

Set generalListOfAddIns = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

End Sub

Public Sub SaveDictAsBin()

Dim Capsule As BinaryCapsuleType
Set Capsule.forObject = generalListOfAddIns

Dim filePath As String
Dim fileNo As Integer
Dim loadedGeneralListOfAddIns As Object

filePath = "C:\TestFolder\ListOfAddIns.bin"
fileNo = FreeFile

Open filePath For Binary Lock Read Write As #fileNo
Put #fileNo, , Capsule
Close #fileNo

End Sub
```

I tried and didnt helped:

- Both early binding and late binding
- Save Dictionary direcly
- Encapsulate Dictionary using the Type statement (as in code example)

I would like to avoid:

- Saving Dictionary content into text files
- Transforming Dictionary into Array for saving purpose
- Adding more references into VBA Project

Which sources didnt helped me (or I dont understand them):

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/can-t-get-or-put-user-defined-type-containing-object-reference
- https://analystcave.com/excel-saving-your-vba-data/

Thank you very much for any help or ideas, RosMane

Comment: As the error says, reference type variables (object, dictionary, collection etc) are a no no. On the other hand, value types (integer, string, date, type etc) are okay. I believe you need to loop and store each key/value pair individually. The same for reading.

Comment: As with the comment above, I would add that this seems like a good use case for creating a class module and defining methods for saving and importing data into the associated dictionary.

Comment: In any programming language, objects must be serialized before being saved to a file. Thus, it will not be possible to avoid the need to turn an object into a string or an array of bytes.